# How to solve 400 bad request error in Netsuite Restlets?

Tags: oauth, netsuite, suitescript, http-status-code-400, restlet-2.0

I am working on a project where I am using restlest to communicate with Netsuite from my website. I am using OAuth 1.0. It was working fine. However, now I face **400 bad request** error. I believed that there was some issue with my code but I tried calling restlet from Postman and still getting the same error.
I have another project which was working fine but now getting the same error. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue. The Signature method before the 2021 release was *HMAC-SHA1 which is now deprecated*. I used the **HMAC-SHA256** method and this resolved the issue.